# ARM cross compilation package not found

Tags: linux, chroot, arm, cross-compilation

I'm trying for arm cross compilation on my `i386` machine using `sysroot` and `chroot`.I want to set environment variables like `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `sysroot`.Right now my code is not compiling because it is not able to find `.pc` files installed on `sysroot` path.I'm using `automake` and when I try to run `configure` script it is throwing that some package is missing.How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Exactly what `.pc` files is it complaining about?  Do those files really exist and it is not finding them, or they just don't exist?  If the latter, you have to cross-compile those packages if you want to cross-compile something that links to them.

Comment: @goldilocks: The `.pc` files are my own packages that I had implemented.Yeah those `.pc` files are exists in the `sysroot` path.And those libraries(packages) were cross compiled for `arm`.Installed from the debians.

Comment: What happens when you call `pkg-config` directly for those?

Comment: It is not getting those `.pc` files path.(I mean it will throw that some package is not found while I run configure script)I know that we can set it to through `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.Those environment variable works for native compilation but not for the cross compilation.Now I read some document where they have specified that cross compilation tool chain itself provides the script file to export the environment variables.So,I'm trying that one.

Comment: @goldilocks: Yeah...Exporting the environment variables in tool chain provided script works.Now the arm cross compilation is working fine. Thanks goldilocks :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting the environment variables in cross compilation tool chain provided script works.